# How can I change a property file value using Maven in a Selenium-Cucumber project?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

> I'm automating a website with selenium/cucumber and i'm trying to change a properties file value from the command line but it does not work.
>
> these are the steps i follow:
> i added in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
  `  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>`
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
     `   <phase>initialize</phase>`
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/properties</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>Config.properties</include>
              </includes>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

This is my config.properties file:
`browser=firefox implicit.wait=10 explicit.wait=10`

And this is my seleniumDriver class:

```
 public static Properties config = new Properties();

    public static Properties OR = new Properties();

    private FileInputStream fis ;
    
    private SeleniumDriver() {
        
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/properties/OR.properties");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            OR.load(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/properties/Config.properties");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            config.load(fis);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        if(config.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
             System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");

            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");

            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

            options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        }else if(config.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "jdk-http-client");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            
        }
```

finally this is the command that I execute in the promt:
`mvn clean install -Dbrowser=chrome test -Dtest=runner.RunCuke`

when I run mvn clean install -Dbrowser=chrome to compile and install the project, I expect the Config.properties file to set the new value I passed to "chrome". Next, with test -Dtesu=runner.RunCuke I expect the test let me open the chrome screen instead this does not happen but takes the default value that is in the Config.properties "firefox".

I also tried writing in the cofig.properties file:
browser=${value}

and then passing in the prompt:
`mvn test -Dtest=runner.RunCuke -Dvalue=chrome`
but it gives me a null point exception